# Highlight current url in menu ith jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a menu but I want to highlight current link with jquery.

```
var loc = window.location;
   var lochref = $("#topNavigation li a").attr("href");

   if(lochref == loc){
       $('#topNavigation li a').addClass('currenthover');
   }
```

With above script, there is no any change in "a" class. How can I do this with jquery?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off: This is something you should consider doing server side. It's much, much, much more simpler and reliable.

Your code compares only the href of the first link, as `attr` returns the property value of the first link. You need to loop over the links to find the right one.

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$("#topNavigation li a").each(function() {
  if(this.href == loc) {
     $(this).addClass('currenthover');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would either log loc and lochref in the console, or do an alert, to see what the values are, it could be as simple as missing a trailing slash. Other than that the code is valid.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/gjZVK/3/

hit run and the 2nd alert should match, and the link will turn red.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used jQuery to highlight the current menu item. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var loc = window.location;
    var pathName = loc.pathname.substring(loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    $('[href$="' + pathName+ '"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.href` off the `window.location` object. You need to change the first line to:

```
var loc = window.location.href
```

Comment: I found this within 1 minute by using firebug and doing a "console.log(window.location)" in the javascript, as Loktar said. Using tools like firebug makes it a lot easier to develop and debug code.