# check URL for text and then add class to li using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My URLs look like this:

```
http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx

http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/casestudies.aspx
```

Here is the menu HTML markup

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx">About Us</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/casestudies.aspx">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I read the URL and look for /aboutus/ and highlight that particular list item?
I would also like to do this with casestudies << this is different as it doesnt have a sub directory.

I would like to use jquery? I think i need to parse the URL? and then check for the words and then add a class or bold to the li ??

**edit**: i want to know what the URL in the browser is, it should match the check in the jquery and then make the li bold or add a class.

Comment: Sounds like this answer does what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958455/highlight-current-url-in-menu-ith-jquery

Comment: no that isnt what i want, when you disable a page within DNN it takes the LI away from the menu so the code will never know if its in the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
$('a[href*="/aboutus/"]').css('color', 'red');
```

See the [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/tGKZZ/1/).

---

**Update:**

If you want to know if the current URL in the browser matches one of the links then use this:

```
$('a[href*="'+window.location.href+'"]').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: this works for checking the a tag in the li.. but i want sommething that checks the URL in the window...? look it doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/tGKZZ/2/

Comment: It looks fine for me, "About Us" is read and "Case Studies" orange.

Comment: Ah, you want to know if the current URL in the browser matches one of the links?!??! Then please update your question...

Comment: This seems to work.. wow so simple as well.. But when i click on a url like this: `http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/csr/healthsafety.aspx` it doesnt want to show `'color', 'red'` on the about us link on the top menu.

Comment: It's because the URL is not exactly the same as the link. If you really want that kind of solution, you probably can't do it with an generic (regexp) solution. Then you have to add each single url to an array or at least each single folder...

Comment: You could open a new question and showing exactly which urls should match which links...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too sophisticated about this approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.sf-menu li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href').match(/aboutus/) && window.location.match(/aboutus/)) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('aboutus-highlight');
        }
        if ($(this).attr('href').match(/casestudies/) && window.location.match(/casestudies/)) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('casestudies-highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably want this if statement instead: `if( this.attr('href').match(/window.location.href.split("/")[4]/) ) {`

Comment: Hmm... I assumed he just wanted to highlight the "aboutus" link.  I didn't see where he said it was dynamic.  I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, he has three possibilities and he wants to highlight the current possibility on his menu. If he didn't want it dynamic he would have manually added the "highlight" class in his stylesheet...

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, I think you are correct.  I sometimes get caught up in answering the question a poster asks instead of what he meant to ask!  Oh well.

Comment: There are 2 scenarios, /aboutus/ and casestudies.aspx, i need to be able to read the word from the URL and match it with the li a then add the class

Comment: Thanks but if you jslint this its buggy

Comment: I fixed the syntaxt but it doesnt add the class.

Answer (score 1):

Give each of your menu elements an ID:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li class="first" id="home"><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li class="" id="aboutus"><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="" id="casestudies"><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/casestudies.aspx">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>
```

And use this jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var currentPage = window.location.href.split("/")[4]);​​​​​​
    $(".sf-menu li")each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href").indexOf(currentPage) > -1) $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
}
```

​

Comment: Because it has syntax errors.. :P and secondly its the window.location i want to compare. You see my "About Us" li is the only one in teh top menu but there are pages that are in that directory which are show in another menu on the page. So i need to check the URL for /aboutus/ and make that top menu link bold. I also need to do the same for casestudies.aspx but this scenario - there isnt a sub directory - so need to just search for the text 'casestudies' from casestudies.aspx

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx") { //whatever } ?>
```

oh you want js, here:

```
<script style='text/javascript'>
function checkURL() {
    if(window.location == "http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/home.aspx") {
    document.getElementById('home').style.background = "yellow";
    } else if (window.location == "http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx") {
    document.getElementById('abgroup').style.background = "yellow";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('casestudies').style.background = "yellow";
    }
}
</script>
<body onload='checkURL()'>
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li class="first" id='home'><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/home.aspx">Home</a></li>
  <li class="" id='abgroup'><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/abgroup.aspx">About Us</a></li>
   <li class="" id='casestudies'><a href="http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/casestudies.aspx">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>
```

yep that works

Comment: This is a javascript question not a php one

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the URL as the href should match it (based on your example), so just this should work.

```
$('a[href=' + window.location.toString() +']').parents('ul').eq(0).addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: No but i have hidden pages for example `http://www.site.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/test.aspx` wont be in the menu but i want the top list item which is "About Us" to have the highlight class.

Comment: Ah fair enough, just grab the first parent of that then (assuming having the class on the UL is good enough but you get the idea just transverse the DOM). I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight any page under /aboutus/ - that is, you don't have just this one page, but several, but you do want the about us menu item to highlight:

```
if(window.location.indexOf('aboutus') != -1){
       $('.sf-menu a[href$="aboutus/abgroup.aspx"]).addClass('here');
 }
```

Then do your styling:

```
.sf-menu .here { background: red; }
```

Or whatever else you want.